# How to follow a URL in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Sorry for the bad title but I don't know how else to phrase "follow".

I'm looking to remotely download a csv file from a website. I could do this by clicking the download button using RSelenium, but I've found that there's a direct link that will initiate the download for me. I.e. I could go to https://www.fake-website-url.com and click the download button, or I could just enter https://www.fake-website-url.com/exportcsv into my browser and it would automatically download.

I try not to use RSelenium whenever I can help it since it's clunky, but I'm not sure how to just initiate the download. Nothing from `rvest` stands out since I'm not actually reading html.

Basically, I'm looking for an R function like `gotoURL('https://www.website.com/exportfullcsv)` that will download the file just like it would if I entered the URL into my browser.

Comment: you could use `download.file('https://www.website.com/exportfullcsv')`

Comment: Hmm looks like I need a destination file for that to work? When I set that up, it returns HTML rather than the download. Now that I think about it, I might have to be logged in to use the direct-download-url, in which case I'd need to use selenium regardless

Comment: oops, yes you need `download.file('https://www.website.com/exportfullcsv', 'temp.csv')` and if it requires login to download I guess `RSelenium` is your option.

Comment: If you can use basic authentication, then perhaps `httr::GET` will do it for you quite easily. If you need a little more, you might need to venture into `rvest::html_session` first, and then `rvest::jump_to` to get to your actual page to get your download link. I think the only time you are likely going to *need* `RSelenium` is if there is javascript that is thwarting any and all efforts to programmatically determine the link.

Comment: Oh wait can you do basic auth with `rvest`? For any auth I've always resorted to `RSelenium` even if JS isn't getting in the way, which obviously isn't ideal. All I need to do is auth and then I can run the url which will download the csv, can that be done without `RSelenium`?

Comment: @r2evans hey got some new info. So I was able to find a direct API link that is referred from `https://www.website.com/exportfullcsv`, meaning I download without being auth'd. But when I do `httr::GET(directURL)` it returns `Status: 200`, `content-type: application/zip` (which is correct), and `Size:  101kb` (correct), but the zip isn't actually downloading. `RSelenium::navigate(directURL)` doesn't work. Could it be downloading to another location? `rvest::html_session(directURL)$response$content` gives me a raw vector of length 101k, but I'm not sure how to work with raw data. Any thoughts?

Comment: The `Size` indicates that you have the content, but it is stored internally in the R object returned from `GET`. If `dl <- GET(...)`, then do `writeBin(httr::content(dl), "file.zip")`.

Comment: Beautiful, that did it!! Wow I would never have guessed that in 1000 years, I was trying every `rawToChar` and `Encoding` function I could find and nothing was working, thanks so much. Now I just need to figure out how to get the signature/expiration for the aws API without signing into the website. The direct download link is in the form `https://fake-website.s3.amazonaws.com/ID=Known-Link?AWSAccessKeyId=Static_Num&Expires=Dynamic_Num&Signature=Dynamic_Num.` The "Expires" and "Signature" update every time you want to download so those are what I need to find without auth'ing. Thanks again!

Comment: @r2evans By the way, if you make this a separate answer I'd be happy to give you the "acceptance"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that you were able to find a direct URL, then the issue is not that the download failed, it's that you aren't accessing the content correctly.

I uploaded a small zip file to a personal website and ran this code:

```r
dl <- httr::GET("https://.../sessions_tracker.zip")
dl
# Response [https://.../sessions_tracker.zip]
#   Date: 2020-04-08 20:59
#   Status: 200
#   Content-Type: application/zip
#   Size: 19.2 kB
# <BINARY BODY>

length(httr::content(dl))
# [1] 19184
19184 / 1000
# [1] 19.184     ### confirmation of download, this rounds to 19.2kB

head(httr::content(dl), n=80)
#  [1] 50 4b 03 04 14 00 00 00 08 00 60 7e 7b 50 1e c3 ed e8 32 4a 00 00 fa b7 01 00 14 00 1c 00
# [31] 73 65 73 73 69 6f 6e 73 5f 74 72 61 63 6b 65 72 2e 63 73 76 55 54 09 00 03 53 83 7e 5e 5e
# [61] 01 85 5e 75 78 0b 00 01 04 d3 c6 2d 00 04 64 00 00 00 b4 5d

writeBin(httr::content(dl), "sessions_tracker.zip")
```